# How to recursively get Excel files stored in a folder in dbfs using pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-commons-dbutils

I have a path mounted in dbfs and I need to extract Excel files path from a given folder and the same folder contains Excel files or sub folder containing Excel files. Current code only gives Excel files in one folder and not in sub folders.

```
files = dbutils.fs.ls('/raw/internal/srange/2018_11_30_00_22_11/')
for file in files:
  if file.path.endswith('xlsx'):
    path = '/dbfs' + file.path[5:]
    print(path)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check for directories as well

```
def walk_dir(dir_path):
    dir_files = dbutils.fs.ls(dir_path)
    excel_files = []
    for file in dir_files:
        if file.isDir():
            excel_files.extend(walk_dir(file.path))
        elif file.path.endswith('.xlsx'):
            excel_files.append(os.path.join('/dbfs', file.path[5:]))
    return excel_files
    
all_excel = walk_dir('/raw/internal/srange/2018_11_30_00_22_11/')
```

I haven't tried the code so it might be buggy.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I recommend:

```
for file1 in dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/raw/internal/srange/2018_11_30_00_22_11/"):
  if '.xlsx' in file1.name:
    print (file1.name)
  for file2 in dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/raw/internal/srange/2018_11_30_00_22_11/"+file1.name):
    if '.xlsx' in file2.name:
      print (file2.name)
    for file3 in dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/raw/internal/srange/2018_11_30_00_22_11/"+file1.name+file2.name):
      if '.xlsx' in file3.name:
        print (file3.name)
```